# Django Validate Bitcoin Address

Tags: django, bitcoin

I'd like to have a Django form which accepts a bitcoin address from a user.  What would be the best way to validate whether or not this address is legitimate?

I could try writing my own implementation, but in regards to these things I'm assuming it's always better to go with something tried and tested than create something with potential holes.  Is there good python code I can use to make a custom field for my django forms, or any resources that have already done this?

Alternatively, might it be better to perhaps skip the whole custom form field process, for example, and validate the address in the view using a pycoin library instead?  If I were to do it this way, however, how would I return the error in the form?

Answer (score 1):

[BCAddressField](https://github.com/kangasbros/django-bitcoin/blob/master/django_bitcoin/BCAddressField.py) acomplishes exactly what I was looking for.  Note however that you must replace `from django.forms.util import ValidationError` with `from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError`, as the former is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Bech32:

```
def btc_validation(address):
    a = str(address)
    length = 0
    valid = False
    not_btc = False
    for i in a:
        length += 1
    if length == 42:
        if a[2] == '1' and a[0] == 'b' and a[1] == 'c':
            for i in a:
                if i == 'O' or i == 'I':
                    not_btc = True
                    break
            if not_btc == True:
                return valid 
            else:
                valid = True
                return valid

        else:
            return 'didn\'t start with bc1'
    else:
        return 'it\'s short'
```

P2PKH:

```
import base58

def bitcoin_address_validation(bitcoinAddress):
    """
    Base58 (P2PKH)
    """
    try:
        base58Decoder = base58.b58decode(bitcoinAddress).hex()
        prefixAndHash = base58Decoder[:len(base58Decoder) - 8]
        checksum = base58Decoder[len(base58Decoder) - 8:]
        hash = prefixAndHash
        for x in range(1, 3):
            hash = hashlib.sha256(binascii.unhexlify(hash)).hexdigest()
        if (checksum == hash[:8]):
            valid = True
        else:
            valid = False
    except:
        valid = False
        pass
    return valid
```

[Reference](https://github.com/16350436/crypto-address-validator/tree/main/Bitcoin)